# Solve by separating variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^y +1$$

I've tried:

$$dy/dt - e^y = 1 $$ $$\Leftrightarrow y' - e^y dt = 1 dt$$

But I'm not sure what to do next or if I'm even doing this right!

Comment: $$
\frac{dy}{dt}=e^y +1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{dy}{e^y+1} = dt \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \int\frac{dy}{e^y+1} = \int dt
$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Why not put as answer?

Comment: I get $$x-\ln(e^y+1) = 0$$

$$y=x$$ This is not correct is it?

Comment: Personally I find:$$ y=t-ln(e^y-1)$$

Comment: The right answer is $$y - \ln(e^y+1)+C = t$$ (with a constant)